# Can MATLAB do realtime motion tracking?

Tags: matlab, tracking, matlab-cvst

I tried to track motion in Matlab by using this tutorial (http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html) and it works fine but it implies video as source to work.

I wanna know if it's possible  to track motion by using the same tutorial but in real time by using camera as source!

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible, just please try to find some stuff by yourself before asking here.

I think you may find the information you need in this link:

http://www.matlabtips.com/realtime-processing/

Alternately, you could of course just store the camera output as a (very short) video and continuously analyse that instead.

Answer (score 0):

As of release R2014a, MATLAB includes [support for USB webcams](http://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/matlab-webcam.html). If you have an older version, or if you want to use a high-end camera, you would need the Image Acquisition Toolbox.

Once you are able to get frames from the camera, you can reuse almost all of the code in the multiple object tracking example. You would only need to rewrite the `readFrame` function with code to get a frame from the camera.